Request failed with exception
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from aiohttp import TraceConfig

class NetworkUsageMonitor(TraceConfig):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.on_request_start.append(self.on_request_start_callback)
        self.on_response_chunk_received.append(self.on_response_chunk_received_callback)
        self.on_request_chunk_sent.append(self.on_request_chunk_sent_callback)
        self.total_received = 0
        self.total_sent = 0
        self.start_time = None

    async def on_request_start_callback(self, session, trace_config_ctx, params):
        self.start_time = asyncio.get_event_loop().time()
        self.total_received = 0
        self.total_sent = 0

    async def on_response_chunk_received_callback(self, session, trace_config_ctx, params, chunk, start_time):
        self.total_received += len(chunk)

    async def on_request_chunk_sent_callback(self, session, trace_config_ctx, params, chunk):
        if chunk:
            self.total_sent += len(chunk)


async def usage_monitor(trace_config):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        elapsed_time = asyncio.get_event_loop().time() - trace_config.start_time
        if elapsed_time > 0:
            total_usage = trace_config.total_received + trace_config.total_sent
            print(f"\033[96m>>Total network usage over the last 5 seconds: {total_usage} bytes")
        else:
            print("\033[91m>No data received in the last 5 seconds.")


async def client(session, trace_config):
    while True:
        try:
            async with session.get('http://httpbin.org/get') as response:
                print('\033[93m>requesting...')
                if response.status == 200:
                    print("\033[92m>-request successful")
                else:
                    print(f"Request failed with status code: {response.status}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"\033[91mRequest failed with exception: {e}")
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

async def main():
    trace_config = NetworkUsageMonitor()
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(trace_configs=[trace_config]) as session:
        tasks = []
        for i in range(2000):
            task = asyncio.create_task(client(session, trace_config))
            tasks.append(task)
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(usage_monitor(trace_config)))
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

In this code,while trying to send requests i get:
Request failed with exception: NetworkUsageMonitor.on_request_chunk_sent_callback() missing 1 required positional argument: 'chunk'
I've tried to invoke on_request_chunk_sent_callback method by many different ways, but I still get this exception. I expect the code to work properly, and print the network usage value, as Task Manager does.

Where is the code that calls this method? (We could get this information if you included the complete error traceback)

As the docs state: Every signal handler should have the following signature: async def on_signal(session, context, params).
